# How to make mailing queue using php's mail() function

Tags: wp-mail, cron, phpmailer

I have a site running WordPress 4.3.1 and a hosts mail() limit of 14 mails per 5 minutes (Which is 2 mails per minute) and cron limit of min 5 minutes, and I am running everyone can register, Profile Builder with mail confirmation and WP Mail Bank to set wp_mail() to php's mail() function. What i need is to limit my mail queue and stimm use mail().

Thanks in forwards!!

P.S. I also have iThemes security with file change notifications.

Comment: Why dont you use SMTP to send the email instead of relying on PHP `mail()`? You can try using https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-wp-smtp/

Comment: Your question is a bit hard to understand. If you're running into a limit on emails you can send from your host, whynot use a service like Mandrill instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your own `wp_mail` function that will override the core one and in your own function you can enqueque emails, and then dequeue them and send them with wp-crom events. Managing the queue is not trivial but should be doable.

But the easier path is to use an external service that has an API like mailchimp.

Comment: I will try Mandrill, like @Evan suggested, and ill get back to you. Thanks!  EDIT: The problem is i have a FREE host, which wont give me DNS settings. And if you can help, how do i code the wp-mail function??

Comment: AFAIK You don't need a DNS setting to use mailchimp API. mandrill is a service by them but it probably offers more then what you need. As for code, it is not trivial and it has too many details for me to think about, and I don't like to provide code for solutions that I don't believe in, as it is probably long term better to either move to a better hosting or use external email sender instead of messing around with something which is close to being core functionality.

Comment: Ok. Thanks, and i found a plugin, and i need to do some little tweaking. Thanks to you and @EvanMattson